# How to migrate laravel migration file to mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I fairly new to laravel and a beginner in monogo db. I have been trying to connect  mongodb cluster of mongodb atlas in my laravel project.
But when I am trying to migrate the laravel migration file it is showing error saying mysql error even after I changed the default connection to mongodb.
Can anyone please tell me how can I fix this issue and migrate the current project to mongodb?

```
PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", "homestead", "secret", [])

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
")
      C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68

      C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68
```

Since laravel doesnt allow mongodb out of the box, so I am using a mongodb package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb 
And I also would like to mention that I have monngodb installed in my php as per the documentation. I can see the confirmation of mongodb on `phpinfo()` page. My settings are as follows:

**My .env**

```
        DB_CONNECTION="mongodb"
        DB_MONGO_PORT=27017
        DB_MONGO_DATABASE=test
        DB_MONGO_DSN="mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-
***.mongodb.net/test"
```

**My config/database.php**

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),

'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'dsn' => env('DB_MONGO_DSN'),
            'database' => env('DB_MONGO_DATABASE'),
        ],
```

**My user migration file**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
//use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why it's not working with the default connection set to mongodb, but I've ran into this problem before. The issue I was having is that the `connection` property in the migration is useless. I had to do the following;

```
Schema::connection($this->connection)->create('collections', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->index('slug');
    $table->index('world_id');
    $table->unique(['world_id', 'slug']);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

`Schema::connection('mongodb')` should work for you.

Comment: how to add indexing on string with mongodb

Comment: @hetalgohel what do you mean?

Answer (score 4):

put `DB_CONNECTION=mongodb` on your **.ENV** file.
Also remove quotes from **MOGN0_DSN** and make sure to call `php artisan config:cache` to dump the autoloaded configuration file

Answer (score 2):

Try this package.

It's easy to use.

https://packagist.org/packages/jenssegers/mongodb

Comment: Yes i am using that package,

Answer (score 1):

Try .env file as

`DB_CONNECTION=mongodb`

without qoutes

Comment: Nope its still not working, still taking that sql connection, even though i have removed all sql credentials from .env

Comment: try composer dumpautoload